# How to push data from html form to firebase realtime database in django(using pyrebase)?

Tags: python, html, django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem with pushing data from a form to firebase realtime database. Here is my view funcction. Just updated to include user token but hasn't helped. The data isn't displaying in the db.

```
def post_add(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    location = request.POST.get('location')
    city = request.POST.get('city')
    website = request.POST.get('website')
    
    
    data = {"name": name, "phone": phone, "location": location, "city": city, "website": website}

    user = authe.get_account_info(request.session['uid'])
    db.child("restaurant").push(data,user['users'][0]['localId'])
    
    return render(request, 'restaurants.html')
```

[here is the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxnud.png)

Just updated to include user token but hasn't helped. The data isn't displaying in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using set() or update() function.

Check the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#update_specific_fields)

```
  const postData = {
    author: username,
    uid: uid,
    body: body,
    title: title,
    starCount: 0,
    authorPic: picture
  };

  // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
  const updates = {};
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  return update(ref(db), updates);
```

This is a Javascript snippet. But it would be mostly same for Python firebase SDK.

For your database the code should look something like this :

```
db.child("restaurant").update(data,user['users'][0]['localId'])
```

Try and let me know. This should work.

**Be careful, set will replace the entire JSON tree for the given key,
*update* won't.**

*ps : But ideally, you should structure your data so that keys are predictable and **unique**.*

Comment: I did that. Only works when i input directly from the code. Could be the path configuration for the form page I presume. I have view function that signs in to that page but takes on the url of the signin form action instead of the page name itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand. Are you saying you don't have the post request data available in your view function "post_add" ?

Comment: I do but it appears the form isn't submitting the data so my assumption is that it might have something to do with the fact that the form page was reached through a "post_sign" function and not directly. Could that be an issue?

Comment: If your form isn't submitting the data, it means you don't have the request data available in your "post_add" function. It has something to do with frontend templates then. 
 If you have your post request data available in your view function then you can use that to update the firebase. I don't seem to understand your problem here. sorry :)
Are you getting any values if you print request.get_json() or request.form, whichever you're using.